# Lemma 4.8 Chapter 7 on Stein and Shakarchi Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, fourier-transform, radon-transform

I am trying to understand this proof of Lemma 4.8 of chapter 7 in page 365 of Real Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi.

Here, $f$ is assumed to be continuous with compact support in $R^d$, and $\hat{f}$ is its Fourier transform.

My question is, how is the change of variables justified? I feel like you can choose a $f$ such that $\hat{f}$ is not so “even”, by shifting $\hat{f}$ as necessary, so those two integrals over the positive reals and the negative reals are not the same. [Link to an image of the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNbZC.jpg)

Edit:
The line is
$$ \int_{S^{d-1}} \int_0^\infty |\hat{f}(\lambda \gamma)|^2 \lambda^{d-1} d \lambda d \sigma(\gamma) = \int_{S^{d-1}} \int_{-\infty}^0 |\hat{f}(\lambda \gamma)|^2 |\lambda|^{d-1} d \lambda d \sigma(\gamma) $$

While typing this out, it occurred to me that is it because the integral over $S^{d-1}$ takes all directions, so changing $\lambda$ to $-\lambda$ does not matter?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: If $f$ is real valued then $\hat f(-x)=\overline {\hat f (x)}$ and $|\overline z| =|z|$.

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos Thanks! I typed it in.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I believe $f$ is assumed to be able to take complex values, but thanks for your comment.